# Getting data from foreign key of other table - TypeOrm(Mysql)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I am using nestjs and typeorm (Mysql). I have these tables users, orders and invoices.
Now invoices table has a foreign key linking to orders table and orders table links to user table.

Now when i am fetching invoices , i want to query user table , but i dont have foreign key for user table instead i have for order table and order table has foreign key for user table.

Is there any way to query user table when fetching invoice data ?

I tried the below code

```
const query = this.createQueryBuilder('invoice');

    query.innerJoinAndSelect('invoice.order', 'order');
    query.innerJoinAndSelect('order.user', 'user');
```

But it is giving this error

```
[Nest] 96607   - 11/09/2021, 11:08:49   [ExceptionsHandler] Relation with property path user in entity was not found.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's more an advice than a solution.

TypeORM is not very intuitive and the documentation is not clear about it.

I reccomend you to change to a futuristic ORM, "PRISMA", the migration is very easy.

After installing it run this commands:

This command generates the schema automatically bassed on your database.

> prisma introspect

This command applies the changes in your prisma schema.

> prisma generate

After that youll have a pretty easy and accurate access to relationships.